# How to remove notepad++ package from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system, notepad++, apt

Earlier I was using Notepad++ and its not user friendly. So I've installed notepadqq now and trying to remove notepad++.

I tried to do but not able to find the package

```
root@ahamed:/home/ahamed/snap# sudo apt remove notepad-plus-plus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package notepad-plus-plus
root@ahamed:/home/ahamed/snap#
```

Now i can see two packages in my machine

```
root@ahamed:/home/ahamed/snap# ls -ltr
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 4 ahamed ahamed 4096 Aug  1 12:01 notepadqq
drwxr-xr-x 4 ahamed ahamed 4096 Aug  1 12:13 notepad-plus-plus
root@ahamed:/home/ahamed/snap#
```

I can see that notepad++ works in .exe format. It really looks weird. Could someone help me on this

```
root@ahamed:/home/ahamed/snap# ps -ef|grep notepad
ahamed   16309  2113  0 12:14 tty2     00:00:00 bash /snap/notepad-plus-plus/85/bin/notepad-plus-plus
ahamed   16421 16309  0 12:14 tty2     00:00:04 /home/ahamed/snap/notepad-plus-plus/85/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus.exe
ahamed   16424     1  0 12:14 ?        00:00:03 /snap/notepad-plus-plus/85/bin/wineserver
root     17134 11542  0 12:23 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto notepad
root@ahamed:/home/ahamed/snap#
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List the installed softwares using the following command, and you will get the list:

```
kswajih@kswajih:~$ sudo snap list
Name               Version            Rev   Tracking  Publisher      Notes
core               16-2.33.1          4917  stable    canonical      core
notepad-plus-plus  7.5.8              85    stable    mmtrt          -
sublime-text       3176               22    stable    snapcrafters   classic
vscode             1.25.1-1531323788  44    stable    flexiondotorg  classic
```

Now use the following command to remove installed packages, in your case its notepad-plus-plus:

```
kswajih@kswajih:~$ sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus 
notepad-plus-plus removed
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That works for me. Thanks and cheers :) 

ahamed@ahamed:/etc/apt$ sudo snap remove notepad-plus-plus
notepad-plus-plus removed
ahamed@ahamed:/etc/apt$